# Can you share a latex template with good formatting for Springer Multimedia Tools and Applications?

Tags: templates

The general latex template provided on the official website has many problems, can you share a latex template with good formatting for Springer Multimedia Tools and Applications to me?

Comment: What exactly are these problems? Normally you should use the template provided by the journal/conference you intend to submit to. There is little point in rolling your own great document class that emulates the looks of the journal/conference proceedings only to find out that they can do nothing with it because you used packages or features incompatible with the publishing workflow. If there are bugs in the template, report them.

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal and they supply a latex class use that class, what the manuscript looks like is not important, what is important is that they can handle that markup for conversion to their published form.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice with publishers is to never overstep the style. That means you shouldn't use any package which is not available in it.

However, if you really have to use one, you should contact your editor and ask him/her if the packages you want to use are okay with their system.